# Классы в CSS и размер шрифта

Tags: html, css

Почему-то я не могу изменить параметры класса "title" в CSS. Что делать? И еще не изменяется параметр font-size, где ошибки?

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Пытался поставить вначале p., не помогло :( */
title {
font-size: 500pt;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
    <metacharset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
        <h1 class="title">Привет.</h1>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно написать `.title` или `h1.title`

Рекомендую пройти вот эту игру, чтобы более подробно разобраться с селекторами.
https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: спасибо :) помогло

Answer (score 1):

класс обозначается через точку:

```
<div class = 'block'></div>

.block {...}
```

идентификатор - через решётку

```
<div id = 'block'></div>

#block {...}
```

тег/блок без каких-то дополнительных символов

```
<div></div>

div {...}
```

В вашем случае вы забыли точку

```
.title {
    font-size: 500pt;
}
```